# asp.net update LINQ dbml files

Tags: asp.net, linq

Is there a quick and easy way to update my LINQ dbml files?

Right now, if I update a Stored Procedure, I need to open the dbml designer file, delete the old SP, save, drag and drop the new SP, and save again. Dont' get me wrong, this isn't "hard"... just with all the fancy new technology out there, it would be nice to be able to just right-click and hit "update".

Comment: I did find this, has anyone used it? http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one seems to do the trick fairly well
http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/

Answer (score 0):

If you are not opposed to a 3rd party solution, CodeSmith's [PLINQO](http://plinqo.com/) is Linq2Sql compatible and lets you regen your DBML while SAVING your customizations. I have been using it maybe a year now and love it.

It does lots more than just let you regenerate your DBML. Check out all the videos on PLINQO.com.

[Here's how to get it free](http://plinqo.com/offer.ashx).